# How to get _id of last record from sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two table "TABLE_EXAM" and "TABLE_QUESTION". I need to store the question in table with exam id. My question is that how to gel last id of exam table?
Thanks in advance..
**Edited Question**
Here is my sample code.

```
public int getLastExamId()
{
    int id2=0;
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * from SQLITE_SEQUENCE", null);
        if(cursor.moveToLast())
        {
            id2=cursor.getInt(0);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return id2;
}
```

Comment: `SELECT MAX(_ID) from TABLE_EXAM`.

Comment: last record means last inserted record?

Comment: you can store id in public var..

Comment: @imrankhan:yes last inserted record....

Comment: you are using AUTOINCREMENT for row id?

Comment: @imrankhan: yes my e_id is autoincrement..

Comment: You want the id of the just inserted record or the maximum most id from the table? both need not be same always

Comment: i need id of the last inserted record..

Answer (score 4):

if you are inserting data using

```
db.insert(TABEL_NAME, null, values);
```

then the return value from this function is the id of the row.

Comment: According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insert%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29 it seems to be correct, but I think it is returning the number of rows affected by the operation because I am always getting 1 when inserting a new record.

Comment: actually it works perfect in my case... I have checked this so, many times for conformation... using debugger and logs